# Asymmetric random walk: calculating the probability that the walk starting from $n$ reaches $N$ before $M$

Tags: probability

Suppose that a random walk on a line is starting from $n$, where $ M\le n \le N$ and $M, n, N \in \mathbb{Z}$. The probability of a jump to the right is $p ∈ (0, 1)$ and the probability of a jump to the left is $q = 1 − p$. The walk stops once it reaches either $M$ or $N$. Let $ r_n $ be the probability that the walk starting from $n$ reaches $N$ before $M$.

> (a) State the equations for $ r_n $, where $ M\le n \le N$ and explain
>   how $ r_M $ and $ r_N $ are obtained.

Honestly, I have no clue how to go about this problem.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know?